# Hyperledger Playground - Credentials for network administrator

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

In the "My Wallet"->"Deploy New Business Network screen" what is the Credentials for network administrator?

I have installed the Dev tools based on the [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html). No problems here, everything was straightforward.

After the installation I've got the playground up and running with the [PeerAdmin card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joVsz.png) created.

My question is related to the creation of a new Business network under the hlfv1 connection.
I filled the basic info, selected a sample network but I'm not understanding the "Credentials for network administrator".
Where should I get these details? 
The peer admin was created by a script in the installation process. I was reading back all the tutorials and still don't get it.

I guess this should be a simple detail that I'm missing but it's really blocking my progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having selected 'your sample network':

1. Click radio button 'id and secret' and enter Enrollment ID and Secret (this is so that it can enrol with the Certificate Authority (provided by the runtime Fabric) and get its certificate/key:

it should default to 'admin' and '******' (the default password 'adminpw')

2. Scroll up, click 'Deploy' on the right
3. 'Connect' as 'admin@trade-network' (or whatever network you chose - there will be a card on the panel)

that's it. Use of this admin id is described here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer//business-network/bnd-deploy (in reference to Playground).

Comment: The link is now dead.